# Using a WHERE clause with count(*)

Tags: mysql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT HBODBED, COUNT(*) FROM OCCASIONS WHERE GROEP = 6 GROUP BY HBODBED
```

It returns this:
[image]
Except I want to use it in a sub-query so that I could use it in a other query's where clause.
To do that I have to return 1 column(`HBODBED`).

To make matters worse I only want to select the rows where COUNT(*) is 1 to 5.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `HAVING` clause, something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM some_other_table
WHERE HBODBED IN (SELECT HBODBED FROM OCCASIONS
                  WHERE GROEP = 6
                  GROUP BY HBODBED
                  HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 1 AND 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the `COUNT` to be returned, just don't include it in the `SELECT`. For conditions over the aggregation function, you can use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT hbodbed 
FROM occasions 
WHERE grouep = 6 
GROUP BY hbodbed 
HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```